# Begginer javascripter having trouble calling functions within functions

Tags: javascript, function

I'm just getting started in JavaScript. I hope you can help me out. I'm trying to call two functions within another function, but it just doesn't seem to work. Nothing shows up on the terminal.

```
function minusOne(n){
    return --n
}
function triple(n){
    return n*3
}
function tripleMinusOne(n){
    tri=triple(n)
    result = anterior(tri)
    return result
}

res=anteriorDelTriple(9)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no function `anteriorDelTriple`

Comment: OP says nothing shows up in console, should it not throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch in the names of the functions. I'm pointing out the corrections to fix the codebase:

```js
function minusOne(n) {
  return --n
}
function triple(n) {
  return n * 3
}
function tripleMinusOne(n) {
  tri = triple(n)
  result = minusOne(tri) // <-- minusOne instead of anterior
  return result
}

res = tripleMinusOne(9) // <-- tripleMinusOne instead of anteriorDelTriple
console.log(res)
```

At this moment, you should be receiving an:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: anteriorDelTriple is not defined
    at <anonymous>:13:1
```

error in the console, and that's the reason why `res` never shows up